# ASP.NET: Path in place of URL arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been taking URL arguments in ASP.NET like so:

`www.mysite.com/thread.php?id=123`

However, I'd like to use the cleaner method that you often see which looks like:

`www.mysite.com/thread/123`

How can I do this (get the arguments) in ASP.NET? What's the usual procedure for setting up a system like this?

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether you're using ASP.net MVC or web forms.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET, but I may want to switch to MVC. Read my response to Nate's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that is called, is Url Rewriting. If you are using the ASP.NET-MVC Framework, you get this behavior by default, along with a design pattern that helps make developing it easier.

If you're trying to shoehorn this onto an existing application, I recommend that you look into some url rewriting modules.

Comment: I've been meaning to ask this; what's difference between creating an ASP.NET website project and creating an ASP.NET MVC application? Is the latter capable of large, user powered, media streaming websites?

Comment: In visual studio, a "website" is just a bunch of aspx files in a folder, in an "application" there is a .prj file that keeps track of what files are in the project.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you're looking for:

[Asp.Net URL Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Comment: This does not require MVC, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Path style arguments can be accessed in C# controller like so. Path argument to be retrieved is "id" which returns a value of "123".

**MVC Routing**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}

//Test URL: http://localhost/MyProject/Test/GetMyId/123
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public string GetMyId()
    {
        //ANSWER -> ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
        return ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
    }
}
```